# QSerialPort error signal on open, but open returns true

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm using Qt 5 and when I open a serialport the open succeeds, but the error signal is immediately received.  I open the port like this:

```
m_serial->setPortName(m_deviceName);
m_serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
m_serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
m_serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
m_serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
m_serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
if (m_serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    qDebug() << "Opened port";
} else {
    qDebug() << "Port error on open:" << m_serial->errorString();
    return;
}
```

and open works (says "Opened port"), but the error slot immediately reports:

> Error num:  0 , msg:  "No such file or directory"

Why is this error being triggered?  After the open I can write & read the port without error (not sure if data is flowing, just no error)

Answer (score 0):

The `QSerialPort` error enum says that 0 is actually no error occurred, the signal is probably being fired when the port is opened to confirm that there's no error. The list of `QSerialPort` errors is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#SerialPortError-enum

Comment: I agree - I just don't understand WHY design wise.  Since the port open function returns true, why issue a signal as well?  (Unless I'm missing something)

Comment: It seems like a strange decision to make, but I'd assume they've built in error emitting for all stages of the connection lifecycle and wanted a guarantee that they'll get something back out.